# Setting MapView region to current geolocation in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, geolocation, react-native-maps

I have a MapView in my React Native app but I'm not sure how I can set its initial location to the device's geolocation. Right now I'm creating a `ref` and updating it with the device's coordinates using the `geolocation` package.

This isn't working though, because whenever I open the app on my phone the region coordinates is `0.0, 0.0` as set initially with `useRef`. The `ref` *is* being updated when my phone moves, the map position just isn't changing. If I zoom out, I can see a marker on my location from the `showsUserLocation` prop. What's wrong with the way I'm trying to update the map's region?

```
 const region = useRef({
    latitude: 0.0,
    longitude: 0.0,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0922,
 });

useEffect(() => {
const watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
  position => {
      const payload = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude,
      };

      axios
        .post('http:localhost:3000/location/update', payload)
        .then(res => {
          region.current = {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          };
        })
  },
  err => console.log(err.response),
);
<MapView
   initialRegion={region}
   initialCamera={{
      center: {
         latitude: region.current.latitude,
         longitude: region.current.longitude,
      },
    }}
    showsUserLocation={true}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using state and also add `region` rather than only just `intialRegion`

```js
const [region,setRegion] = useState({
    latitude: 0.0,
    longitude: 0.0,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0922,
 });

useEffect(() => {
const watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
  position => {
      const payload = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude,
      };

      axios
        .post('http:localhost:3000/location/update', payload)
        .then(res => {
          setRegion({
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          })
        })
  },
  err => console.log(err.response),
);
<MapView
   initialRegion={region}
   region={region}
   initialCamera={{
      center: {
         latitude: region.current.latitude,
         longitude: region.current.longitude,
      },
    }}
    showsUserLocation={true}
/>
```

Hope it helps